# Parametric Region Plot

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions, regions

I tried to find solution in a few discussions but I couldn't solve my problem because my knowledge is basic.

I have the following functions and parameters:

```
Mstar[d_, u_, p_] := ProductLog[-d p + p u];

PIstar[d_, u_, p_] := u - E^-Mstar[d, u, p] (u - d);

CMstar[d_, u_, p_] := 1/2 Mstar[d, u, p]^2;

EUY1star[d_, u_, p_] := PIstar[d, u, p] p - CMstar[d, u, p];

EUB1star[d_, u_, p_, r_, s_] := r (1 - PIstar[d, u, p]) - 2 PIstar[d, u, p] s r;

EUB2star[d_, u_, p_, r_, s_] := r (1 - d) - 3 d s r - EUY1star[d, u, p];

d = 0.2;
u = 0.8;
r = 1;
```

and I want to draw the Parametric Region Plot of

`[{EUB2star[d, u, p, r, s] - EUB1star[d, u, p, r, s] > 0 && EUB2star[d, u, p, r, s] > 0}, {p, 0, 1000}]`

where in the horizontal axis I need `PIstar[d, u, p]` and in the vertical axis `{s, 0, 2}`.

I have no idea how to do it yet in my V.8. Pls help.
Maurizio.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: For the given value of `{d,u,r}`, the condition `{EUB2star[d, u, p, r, s] - EUB1star[d, u, p, r, s] > 0 && EUB2star[d, u, p, r, s] > 0}` is not `True` for any (p,s) in the range you have given. 
Also `PIstar[d, u, p]` is complex.

Comment: Hi Hubble07. I am a bit puzzled about your answer. I tell you why. Originally I plotted the following non-overlapping regions: RegionPlot[{EUB2star[d, u, p, r, s] - EUB1star[d, u, p, r, s] > 0 && EUB2star[d, u, p, r, s] > 0, EUB2star[d, u, p, r, s] - EUB1star[d, u, p, r, s] < 0 && EUB1star[d, u, p, r, s] > 0, EUB1star[d, u, p, r, s] < 0 && EUB2star[d, u, p, r, s] < 0}, {p, 0, 10}, {s, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Green}, MaxRecursion -> 10]

Comment: @M.Lisciandra Sorry, I made a silly mistake by checking only integer values using `Table`. Anyway checkout the answer i posted.

Answer (score 2):

### Version 2

How about writing all your function in terms of $\pi^*$ and then plotting them from `0.2` to `0.8` like this

```
 region = RegionPlot[{r (1 - d) - 
  3 d s r - (pstar*(Log[(u - d)/(u - pstar)]/(u - 
         pstar)) - (Log[(u - d)/(u - pstar)])) - (r (1 - pstar) - 
    2 pstar*s r) > 0 && 
  r (1 - d) - 
  3 d s r - (pstar (Log[(u - d)/(u - pstar)]/(u - 
         pstar)) - (Log[(u - d)/(u - pstar)])) > 0}, {pstar, 0.2, 
  0.8}, {s, 0, 2}, MaxRecursion -> 10, 
 FrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Pi]\), \(*\)]\)", "s"}, 
  RotateLabel -> False, LabelStyle -> (FontSize -> 20)]
```

For the transformation I used the inverse function for `ProductLog`

If $b = ProductLog(a)$ then $a = b*e^{b}$

Using above we can write

$$p(u-d)=M^* e^{M^*}$$

This allows to write $p$ in terms of $\pi^*$

$$M^* = Log\left(\frac{u-d}{u-\pi^*}\right)$$

$$p= \frac{1}{u-\pi^*}Log\left(\frac{u-d}{u-\pi^*}\right)$$

With the above transformation you can express all your inequality in terms of $\pi^*$.
Since $\pi^*$ ranges from $u$ to $d$ for $p$ going from $0$ to $\infty$, you can then `RegionPlot` $\pi^*$ from u to d. This is what I have shown.

[image]

---

Can't you just find the range of $\pi^*$ for the range of $p$ and then plot over that range.

```
  regPlot[pmax_, smax_] := 
  Module[{pmin = 0, smin = 0, PIstarMin, PIstarMax},

  PIstarMin = PIstar[d, u, pmin];
  PIstarMax = PIstar[d, u, pmax];

  RegionPlot[{EUB2star[d, u, p, r, s] - EUB1star[d, u, p, r, s] > 0 &&
  EUB2star[d, u, p, r, s] > 0}, {p, PIstarMin, PIstarMax}, {s, 0, 
  smax}, MaxRecursion -> 10, 
  FrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Pi]\), \(*\)]\)", "s"}, 
   RotateLabel -> False, LabelStyle -> (FontSize -> 20)]]
```

So for $p_{max}=1000$ and $s_{max}=2$ we get

```
   regPlot[1000, 2]
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Hubble07, you're just great!  I have a question though. The variable 'p' goes from 0 to infinity (because this is my definition of the variable). I put p=[0,1000] just for simplicity. 'PIstar' is a probability and it is simply a function of 'p', given 'd' and 'u', which are the lower and upper bounds of 'PIstar' respectively. Thus 'PIstar' is fully described by the whole range of 'p=[0,+infinity or 1000]'. Hence, the plot you gave me describes 'PIstar' values for 'p' that goes from 0 to 1000. Is it correct?  Thank you again!!

Comment: Thanks.
Actually in the plot $\pi^*$ goes upto 0.8 which is infact the limiting value for $p \rightarrow \infty$. I mean $lim_{p \rightarrow \infty}\pi^*(a,b,p)=b$. You can check this in mma `Limit[PIstar[a, b, p], p -> Infinity]`. Here its 0.8 since you have set that limit by `u=0.8`. So you can sat that, "The plot describes $\pi^*$ values for $p$ going from 0 to $\infty$"

Comment: I'm afraid there is a problem with the solution you gave me! I did a double check. First, consider simply EUB1star>0, I plotted parametrically the boundary `ParametricPlot[{PIstar[d, u, p], (1 - PIstar[d, u, p])/(2 PIstar[d, u, p])}, {p, 0, 1000}, AspectRatio -> 1/1, 
 PlotRange -> {{d, u}, {0, 2}}, MaxRecursion -> 15, 
 AxesOrigin -> {d, 0}]` ... the region plot is actually the area beneath the curve. Then, I used the regionplot you suggested just for `EUB1star[d, u, p, r, s] > 0` but the areas are different! Any suggestions? Sorry if I take some of your time.... Thank you.

Comment: I've just realized that with your script you've just plotted simply this: `RegionPlot [{EUB2star[d, u, p, r, s] - EUB1star[d, u, p, r, s] > 0 &&
  EUB2star[d, u, p, r, s] > 0}, {p, 0.2, 0.8}, {s, 0, 2}, 
 MaxRecursion -> 10]`, as @belisarius did before.

Comment: I don't see any problem in `Regionplot` for `EUB1star[d, u, p, r, s] >0` given by my function. What do you expect?. It agrees with `Plot[EUB1star[d, u, 0.2, r, s], {s, 0, 2}]`. I mean the maximum `s` value allowed is around 1.4. In your `ParametricPlot` whats the expected value of Y-coordinate at `p=0.2`. It should be the value of  `(1 - PIstar[d, u, 0.2])/(2 PIstar[d, u, 0.2])` right which is around `1.4` so it matches  with the cutoff in the `RegionPlot`.

Comment: Dear @Hubble07 you're still confusing `PIstar[d, u, p]` with `p`. Consider that in the X-axis I need `PIstar[d, u, p]`, not `p`. E.g., the intercept of (1 - PIstar[d, u, p])/(2 PIstar[d, u, p]) as `p=0`, i.e. `PIstar[d, u, p]=0.2`, is 2 (i.e. s=2). Hope I made it clear. I need to plot `EUB1star[d, u, p, r, s]>0` for the values of `PIstar[0.2, 0.8, p]` (i.e. X-axis), which lies between 0.2 and 0.8, for all values of p (i.e., from zero to infinity) describing `PIstar[0.2, 0.8, p]`. Otherwise, I could simply do a RegionPlot as I said in the previous comment. Sorry for the fuss, hope you can help.

Comment: Consider that my original need is `{EUB2star[d, u, p, r, s] - EUB1star[d, u, p, r, s] > 0 && EUB2star[d, u, p, r, s] > 0}`. If I had only one inequality (i.e., one region) I could do a `ListLinePlot` and `Table`, but I need the intersection of two regions. Thank you again.

Comment: OK just tell me this , if I do a `RegionPlot` for only one condition i.e. `EUB1star[d, u, p, r, s] >0` and with `s` on the Y-axis going from `0 to 2`and $\pi^*$ on the X-axis going from `0.2 to 0.8`, how should the `Regionplot` look? Do you know the expected result? Can you roughly  draw it by hand and show me? I mean how would it differ from the simple `RegionPlot [{EUB1star[d, u, p, r, s] > 0}, {p, 0.2, 0.8}, {s, 0, 2}, MaxRecursion -> 10]`

Comment: Ignore my previous comment. I understand it know. So the expected result is the `ParametricPlot` you showed right
`ParametricPlot[{PIstar[d, u, 
   p], (1 - PIstar[d, u, p])/(2 PIstar[d, u, p])}, {p, 0, 1000}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/1, PlotRange -> {{u, d}, {0, 2}}, 
 MaxRecursion -> 15, AxesOrigin -> {d, 0}]`

Comment: Yes @Hubble07! Now the problem is to plot the intersection of two parametric regions `{EUB2star[d, u, p, r, s] - EUB1star[d, u, p, r, s] > 0 && EUB2star[d, u, p, r, s] > 0}` in the plane `PIstar[d, u, p]` and `s`. Actually, I have other two regions, that complete the plane, which are `{EUB2star[d, u, p, r, s] - EUB1star[d, u, p, r, s] < 0 && EUB1star[d, u, p, r, s] > 0}` and `{EUB1star[d, u, p, r, s] < 0 && EUB2star[d, u, p, r, s] < 0}`. But once I have the script for the first region I can easily (hopefully) plot the remaining two regions. Hope you can help (@belisarius too I hope). Cheers.

Comment: Check the edit. Is that correct. Please verify the transformations.

Comment: Dear @Hubble07, I'm afraid also this time the graph should not be correct! In your answer I plotted `EUB2star[d, u, p, r, s] > 0`, beneath its plot we have one of the two regions whose intersection I am trying to find out. Your region lies also above the red curve, so it cannot be correct! I have difficulties to follow your transformation, but I can't see how you could ever transform `EUY1star[d, u, p]`. Isn't there a sort of RegionPlot with Parametric functions?? I am really stack. Hope you can help me... Maurizio.

Comment: I have shown the inverse transformation used for the plots which looks correct. Now I don't see how else to achieve what you want. This is all I got and I think its time for me to say `I quit`. Sorry hope someone else helps you. Good-luck!

Answer (score 2):

```
RegionPlot[{EUB2star[d, u, p, r, s] - EUB1star[d, u, p, r, s] > 0 && 
           EUB2star[d, u, p, r, s] > 0}, 
           {p, 0, 2}, {s, 0, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: The OP said they need `PIstar[d, u, p]` along the X-axis not simply `p`.

Comment: Yes. Indeed. Thank you Belisarius by the way.